# way to promote databrick workflow job in higher environemnt using azure cicd

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-databricks

looking for option to promote databrick workflow job to higher environment where the job is created from UI and not through code . DBX and job  export import option checked. not working. Trying to find databricks api for the same .

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Databricks API documentation.

Here is a sample request:

```py
import requests

base_url = "https://<WORKSPACE_URL>"
api_token = "<API_TOKEN>"

job_id = "<EXISTING_JOB_ID>"
export_url = f"{base_url}/api/2.0/jobs/runs/export?job_id={job_id}"
response = requests.get(export_url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {api_token}"})
job_definition["new_field"] = "new_value"

create_url = f"{base_url}/api/2.0/jobs/reset"
response = requests.post(create_url, json=job_definition, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {api_token}"})
UpdatedJobInfo = response.json()

print("Job updated with ID:", UpdatedJobInfo["job_id"])
```

Add this script to your repo, in your pipeline use a command shell task to run it. Store the api token in repo as a secret and use it as a env. variable in your pipeline. Just note that this is a sample request, so please go through and make changes as necessary.

---

Source: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/jobs-api-updates)

Comment: Thanks for the response - but this is creating the job - where i struggle is to update the job id - once the job is created how to update the job schedule etc parameter etc as the idea is to update through azureDevOps pipeline only .  @Ziya Mert Karakas

Comment: @RubenSo, changed the script for update, and gave you general instructions.